# C ++ Stack Memory Usage

Tags: c++

As a c ++ beginner, I have a problem with when variables should be used in methods and when in classes. For example, does define a variable that we send continuously in the method as below and defining it in the header file means the same thing for memory?

```
void my_method()
{
int my_val=0x04;
Send(my_val);
}
```

Is this usage wrong?my_val variable is re-created each time.

or in the header file define and in .cpp use it

```
class my_class
{
int my_val;
};
```

Comment: If the compiler sees that `my_val` is constant, it will optimize it to `Send(0x04)` and no variable is created. If however, you were to assign a value to that variable later on, it "might" not optimize it away. In the `my_method` function it will become `Send(0x04)`. If optimizations are off or it doesn't get optimized away, yes it will be created every time.

Comment: @Brandon Then is there a difference between defining it as const in the method and defining it as const in the header?

Comment: @eLigt You should mainly worry to place `my_val` where it fits better. If it is a value that every instance of `my_class` should have, then make it a member variable. If it is just a value used by `my_method` to perform whatever, make it a local variable to `my_method`.

Comment: I don't see how the 2 code snippets are related. Sure, both use the same name for the variables, but you cannot access a private member from outside the class and there's not a single function in your class that would have access to the member variable.

Comment: In general, variables that are *shared* by two or more methods should be declared in the class.  Variables that are **only** used in the method should be declared in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting the dots on the i here (forgive me for being verbose).

If your class *my_class* has a method *my_method* and *my_val* is defined in the class instead of the method, when you instantiate *my_class* you get an object, along with its attributes, that resides either in the heap or in the stack (depending on whether you used **new** to allocate it or not), and it will exists until the destructor of the object is called.

If *my_val* is defined inside the method, when the method is called, the variable is created and initialised in the stack (in this specific case). When the method terminates executing the stack is rolled back and your variable stops existing.

Now, suppose your *send* function is non-blocking and you pass *my_val* by reference instead of by value, in such case you have dangling reference. Thus the choice of where placing the variable can depend on several aspects.